# Responsive CSS grid without media query

Tags: html, css, grid, responsive

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  background-color: #20262e;
}

ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: max-content 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.a {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}

.b {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}

.c {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

.d {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class=a>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br></li>
  <li class=b>B</li>
  <li class=c>C</li>
  <li class=d>D</li>
</ul>
```

I would like for the grid to collapse into a single column with list items taking 100% width when they reach 300px.

Is this possible without having to do a media query like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    ul {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: you will have more chance with flexbox .. gird doesn't handle wrapping like you expect

Answer (score -2):

As stated in comments, [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) is probably a better choice here if you wish to avoid media queries. Key here is to declare `flex-wrap: wrap;` on parent. You will have to restructure your `html` to accommodate a column since `ul` can't have any children other than `li`.

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  background-color: #20262e;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 270px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.a {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}

.b {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}

.c {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

.d {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class=a>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br></li>
  <li class=b>B</li>
  <li class=c>C</li>
  <li class=d>D</li>
</ul>
```